# what is the fastest way to bulk update products using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to update 500,000 rows using a txt file which is previosly formatted to get the right data.
After formatting I push it to an array name $parts and loop thru it to start updating the rows, but the process seems slow . is there a faster way to perform the same task? does the column on the MYSQL table has to be a special key?

```
    foreach($parts as $part){
        \Log::channel('bulk_update_log')->info($part['part_number']);
        DB::table('products')
            ->where('part_number', $part['part_number'])
            ->update(
                [
                    'product_name' => $part['part_name'],
                    'price' => $part['part_price'],
                ]
            );
    }
```

Comment: what makes it slow is the where statement. So unless your input is in the very same order than your table rows (which would allows you to remove the where), you wont get many more speed

Comment: That heavily depends on your application. What have you tried to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are going to be able to drastically improve the time it takes to import 500k rows. However, to make it more reliable since you're using Laravel you could consider creating a Job that will perform the update of each row, so you process your 500k rows dispatching each line of data to a Job then run a queue worker (even locally) to process each one. It's not going to be any faster but it will be more reliable to make sure every row of data is processed and you can see failed jobs to make sure every job runs.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#creating-jobs

Answer (score 0):

For what you are doing, `INDEX(part_number)` is highly desirable.

If you are replacing the entire table, then use `LOAD FILE` to populate a new table, the swap tables.  (This solution is not applicable if the text file has only price changes, not the other rows or columns for unchanged products.)

If you are updating only some of the rows,

0. Be sure to have the index (or `PRIMARY KEY`) mentioned above.
1. `LOAD DATA` into a temp table (no indexing needed).
2. Use a multi-table `UPDATE` to copy the values into the main table.

If you want to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I tried indexing the part number, it helps but not much.If a new temp table is created with only the columns i need to update (which are only three) and just copy the values I need to the main table using the part number(not primary key) would that speed up the process?

Comment: @CristianAndes - I elaborated on `LOAD FILE` and why it does not apply.  Let's see the multi-table UPDATE you wrote.  (Please provide the generated SQL; I am not fluent in Laravel-speak.)

Comment: ok creating the temp table and inserting the rows its a fast process I'm trying to update the products table using this query: UPDATE products INNER JOIN temp_products ON temp_products.part_number = products.part_number SET temp_products.part_price = products.price;

Comment: @CristianAndes - That looks backwards; don't you need to `SET products...`?

Comment: Yes thanks !what do you recommend to update the products table faster?